# Using Retrofits2 upload file to server in android

Tags: android, server, retrofit2

Why can not I upload files to the server? When I used Log.d to print to the log screen, it reported an error can not connect to 192.168.10.2:8080 although I have asked for permission to the Internet and read the internal memory of the device.

**APIUtils.java**

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public class APIUtils {
    public static final String Base_Url = "http://192.168.10.2:8080/Quanlysinhvien/";

    public static DataClient getData(){

        return RetrofitClient.getClient(Base_Url).create(DataClient.class);
    }
}
```

**DataClient.java**

```
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Multipart;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Part;

public interface DataClient {

    @Multipart
    @POST("uploadhinhanh.php")
    Call<String> UploadPhot(@Part MultipartBody.Part phto);
    }
```

**RetrofitClient.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseurl){
        OkHttpClient builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                .build();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseurl)
                .client(builder)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

**DangKyActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.nhutkhanh.demoretrofit2.Retrofit2.APIUtils;
import com.example.nhutkhanh.demoretrofit2.Retrofit2.DataClient;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class DangKyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imgdangky;
    EditText edtUsername, edtPassword;
    Button btnhuy, btnxacnhan;
    int Request_Code_Image = 123;
    String realpath = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dang_ky);
        anhxa();
        imgdangky.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, Request_Code_Image);
            }
        });
        btnxacnhan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(realpath);
                String file_path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                String[] mangtenfile = file_path.split("\\.");

                file_path = mangtenfile[0] + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + mangtenfile[1];
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/from-data"), file);

                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("uploaded_file", file_path, requestBody);

                DataClient dataClient = APIUtils.getData();
                retrofit2.Call<String> callback = dataClient.UploadPhot(body);
                callback.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                        if(response != null){
                            String message = response.body();
                            Log.d("AAA", message);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("BBB", "Lỗi " + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == Request_Code_Image && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            realpath = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                imgdangky.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    public String getRealPathFromURI (Uri contentUri) {
        String path = null;
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return path;
    }
    private void anhxa() {
        imgdangky = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewDK);
        edtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDKMK);
        edtUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDKTK);
        btnhuy = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHuy);
        btnxacnhan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonXacNhan);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Genymotion` ?

Comment: No I use the virtual machine of android studio and my smartphone.

Comment: before looking into the code, try to have a look at the firewall of your localhost server. I have faced similar issue before and it's because my antivirus firewall block my http request..

Comment: How can I turn off the firewall?

Comment: @NhutKhanhLe normally you can check your blocked traffic in your antivirus software... just unblock your device in case the firewall really blocked your request. though that might not be the real cause, i think it is worth a check

Comment: @jackycflau Thanks for your answer